# Form Input Not showing in Request.POST

Tags: javascript, html, django, dropzone.js, dropzone

I'm trying to create a form where I'm using Dropzone but I need to add another input. The problem is that from the server when I try to access the other input, the server could not find it.

This is the html code I'm have atm

```
{% load static %}

{% block content %}


<div class="pt-3 pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">

        <form action="#" method="POST" class="dropzone dz" id="dropzone" name="dropzone" >
            {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="fallback" >
                    <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
                    <input type='text' name='fullname' value='what ever you need to get in backend'>
                </div>
        </form>


        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" id='uploadfiles' value='Submit' >Submit</button>
            <span data-feather="save"></span>
            Submit
        </button>-->

</div>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/jq-3.3.1/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.20/b-1.6.1/b-html5-1.6.1/b-print-1.6.1/datatables.min.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/jq-3.3.1/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.20/b-1.6.1/b-html5-1.6.1/b-print-1.6.1/datatables.min.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript">

    $('#dropzone').submit(function() {
      console.log('Hello');
    });



    Dropzone.options.dropzone =
             {
                autoProcessQueue: false,
                maxFiles: 1,
                acceptedFiles: ".xlsx",
                addRemoveLinks: true,

                  init: function() {
                    var submitButton = document.querySelector("#uploadfiles")
                        myDropzone = this; // closure

                    submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
                      var a = document.getElementById('pymt_date').value
                      var CurrentDate = new Date();
                      GivenDate = new Date(a);
                      if (a == null || a == ""){
                        alert("Please Enter Payment Date");
                        return false;
                      }
                      else if (GivenDate < CurrentDate) {
                        alert("Payment Date Must be greater than today");
                        return false;
                      }
                      else {
                          console.log(document.getElementById('pymt_date').value);
                          myDropzone.processQueue();
                          setTimeout(function() {
                                location.reload();
                            }, 5000);
                          }
                       // Tell Dropzone to process all queued files.
                    });
                  }
            };

</script>
```

Can you please help and advise what is the issue. When I try to print request.POST in order to get the value of the input name="fullname"  all I'm getting is the csrf token and that's it.

Comment: `<form enctype="multipart/form-data" ...>`.

Comment: The files are by the way accessible through `request.FILES`, not `request.POST`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I'm not referring to the file. The file I confirm I do have access to it. I need to get the value of the input name = fullname. That I cannot access it with request.POST

Comment: I don't see the id of `dateform` attached to the form which contains the `<input>` tag for fullname. Maybe update the reference and check.

Comment: @SaranshSingh the form id and name is dropzone .. dateform is not that form..  the issue is that i need to process the file and the input fullname in the same request ..

Answer (score 0):

first of all your submit button is out of the form. Imo should be inside and the type of the button should be 'submit' not 'button'. Another thing it's not clear where u want to have access to request.POST. In the Django view? So in the form make: enctype="multipart/form-data as Willem Van Onsem said. And once again place submit button inside the form. So u will be able to handle POST request in the view. And review your code u've got a few mistakes - twice closing , Submit etc.